# How to create a simple RTMP apache server for streaming audio files

Tags: apache, audio, streaming, broadcast, rtmp

The only thing I could find with the same title is [howto create a simple web page that plays a RTMP stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792329/howto-create-a-simple-web-page-that-plays-a-rtmp-stream). and that is NOT my question, since I'm not asking about the web page. My question is about setting up a simple RTMP server on apache without sophisticated and high-tech technologies.

Thank you for advice

Comment: Just to clarify - you'd like to make the audio streaming via RTMP and make it via Apache somehow, is that correct? What is the input format for your audio files?

Comment: That's true, my input file would be MP3, but AAC is also ok.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Wowza should be able to do that as part of RTMP VOD streaming. The URL should look like rtmp://domian.com/app/mp3:filename

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be Apache? Nginx has an RTMP module that is relatively easy to implement, and you can indeed use Wowza as well.